# How to make two tables next to each other on a single page with two columns

Tags: tables, formatting

This is what I have done.

````
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c| } 
\hline
Notation & Definition \\
\hline
$\Lambda$ & Birth rate \\ 
$\mu$ & Natural death rate \\ 
$\alpha$ & Rate of death due to COVID 19 \\ 
$\beta$ & Transmission rate \\ 
$\delta$ & Rate of vaccination \\ 
$\lambda$ & Vaccine efficiency \\ 
$\epsilon$ & Rate at which exposed become infectious \\ 
$\gamma$ & Rate of recovery \\ 
$\zeta$ & Rate at which newly vaccinated people gain full immunity \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{doublespace}
\captionof{table}{Definition of symbols and notation}

\begin{doublespace}

\begin{flushleft}
\begin{center}
\pagestyle{fancy}
To begin we can define the following:```
````

Comment: Please extend your code sniped to MWE (Minimal Working Example), a small but complete document, which show your problem. If tables should be paralel, than only option is to put them in the ˙table*˙ environment. This environment has limited positioning possibilities, however packages  `stfloats` and `cuted` extend it (significantly.)

Comment: Also, it needs to be clearer what the actual issue is. There's only one table in your sample code. What is supposed to go next to what? Does the rest of your document have two columns? Unrelated, but putting `\begin{center}` right after `\begin{flushleft}` as you do near the end does not make any sense.